# Get the color of a point on a geometry face

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using THREE.js to render my scene and I got a tricky question - how can I get the color of a specific point on a geometry face?

By color, I don't mean the face or material color, I mean the actual output color at the specific point, based on: material, face color AND texture color at the specific location.  for example, if the texture on the face at given point is red, and the material color is half visible (alpha = 0.5), what I expect to get is: (r=1.0, g=0.0, b=0.0, a=0.5).

Note: performance is important.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and straightforward way would be to do it with `<canvas>`.

```
var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
canvas.width = renderer.domElement.width;
canvas.height = renderer.domElement.height;

var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
context.drawImage( renderer.domElement, 0, 0 );

var imagedata = context.getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
var data = imagedata.data;

var index = ( mousex + ( mousey * canvas.width ) ) * 4;

var red = data[ index ];
var green = data[ index + 1 ];
var blue = data[ index + 2 ];

var hex = red << 16 | green << 8 | blue << 0
```

Answer (score 0):

enabled  Well actually what you expect to get is not true. You are not considering lights. With no lights your object will be black. With lights and depending on the location of the light you will get different results. Even if you use flat shading the color of the face will depend on its normal.

Comment: alright let's narrow down the question - let's assume ambient is always 0xffffff, and I'll ignore vertices colors for now - just material color.  this means the tricky part is just to get the texture color at given location, based on uv and point on surface. any ideas?  thanks

Comment: You would have to RenderToTexture in order to get that info.